# How to make text stored as date independent of the computers date formats when calculating age?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

Hi i have this 2 columns and cell F1 have this formula:

```
=ROUND(((TEXT("05/07/2019","dd/MM/yyyy")-TEXT(E1,"dd/MM/yyyy"))/365),2)


       |      E        |      F      |
 1        15/03/2019       #VALUE!
```

I believe this error is caused because when the computers date format is changed to M/d/yyyy it inteprets cell E1 as M/d/yyyy, but i stored cell E1 as a text in dd/MM/yyyy so that the format wont keep changing on computers with different date formats and my excel sheet can be uniformed on all computers. but in the formula it is giving me an error because there is no '15th' month as some computers format their date to M/d/yyyy, so is there a way to create a formula that takes the text in cell E1 as it is("dd/MM/yyyy")?

Comment: It's working Fine in My system. You are using the Function without `[]` ?

Comment: @Mikku yes the brackets are just there for show only, the actual text is =ROUND(((TEXT("05/07/2019","dd/MM/yyyy")-TEXT(E1,"dd/MM/yyyy"))/365),2)

Comment: @Mikku it works fine when the computers date format is changed to dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: I am getting an Answer `0.31` ...No Error .... What is the Format of E1 ?

Comment: Can you try and change the Format in Formula to your computers Format ? that Should work

Comment: Like this `=ROUND(((TEXT("07/05/2019","mm/dd/yyyy")-TEXT(E1,"mm/dd/yyyy"))/365),2)`

Comment: @Mikku its general, i dont want it to be in date format because i want the date  to be fixed as it is and if the cell is in date format it will keep changing to the computers date format setting, and  i cant change the format in the formula as this excel formula is auto generated by a program i made, i need the formula to be fixed and independent of the computers date format. like making excel take the cell E1 as 'dd/MM/yyyy' even if the computers date format is "M/d/yyyy"

Comment: i can change the formula setting in my program but i need a fixed format so that the formula works across all computers with different date formats

Comment: So what you can do is ... Change the Date present in E1 to your formula readable format using this Function `=TEXT(CONCAT(DAY(E1),"/",MONTH(E1),"/",YEAR(E1)),"dd/mm/yyyy")` , then u can pass on the result to your Formula.

Comment: I assume that you want to calculate the difference between "05/07/2019" and the date in `E1` then divide to 365. So you can make both of them as the date and then do the calculation. 
     `=ROUND((DATE(2019;7;5)-DATE(RIGHT(E1;4);MID(E1;FIND("/";E1;1)+1;FIND("/";E1;FIND("/";E1;1)+1)-FIND("/";E1;1)-1);LEFT(E1;2)))/365;2)`

My excel accepts `;` you can change them to comma `,`.

Comment: You may be making things more complicated than necessary.  Excel stores dates as serial numbers, and you can operate on them no matter the formatting if they are stored that way (as "real" dates would be).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld oh thanks for that suggestion, im new to excel and excel formulas so i do not know much about how dates work in excel